# Ajax ActionLink in MVC Razor View

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

In my demo MVC Application I have a Student and a Department Model class.

```
public class Student
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int StudentId { get; set; }
    public String LastName { get; set; }
    public String FirstName { get; set; }
    public String UserName { get; set; }
    public String Password { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Department")]
    public int DepartmentID { get; set; }

    //Department Navigational Property
    public Department Department { get; set; }
}
```

and

```
 public class Department
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int DepartmentID { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage="Department Name cannot be empty")]
    public String DepartmentName { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Department Code cannot be empty")]
    public String DepartmentCode { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Student> Students { get; set; }
}
```

The StudentViewModel looks like :

```
    public class StudentViewModel
{
    public Student Student { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "StudentName")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Student Name cannot be left blank")]
    public String StudentFullName
    {
        get
        {
            return String.Format("{0} {1}", Student.FirstName, Student.LastName);
        }
    }

    public String UserName { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    public String Password { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Compare("Password",ErrorMessage="Passwords do not match")]
    [Display(Name="Confirm Password")]
    public String C_Password { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Department Name")]
    public String DepartmentName { get; set; }

}
```

The initializer data for them in the StudentEFInitializer class are :

```
    protected override void Seed(StudentContext context)
    {
        var departments = new List<Department>
        {
            new Department {DepartmentName="CSE",DepartmentCode="CS101"},
            new Department {DepartmentName="ECE",DepartmentCode="EC197"},
            new Department {DepartmentName="MECH",DepartmentCode="MC202"}
        };

        departments.ForEach(d => context.Departments.Add(d));
        context.SaveChanges();

        var students = new List<Student> {
            new Student {FirstName = "Zack",LastName="Dyas", UserName ="zack_dyas",DepartmentID=1,Password ="zack123"},
            new Student {FirstName = "Abraham",LastName="D'Pedro",UserName ="ab_dpedro",DepartmentID=2,Password ="ab123"}
        };

        students.ForEach(s => context.Students.Add(s));
        context.SaveChanges();

    }
}
```

Now in my action view MyAction.cshtml first I show them the all the registered user names using ajax.actionlink.

```
@model IEnumerable<MvcApplication4.ViewModels.StudentViewModel>  
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "MyAction";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_myTemplateLayoutPage.cshtml";
}


<div id="content">
    <div id="mainpage">

    <h2>Registration Details</h2>
        <ul>
        @foreach(var item in Model) 
        {
            <li>
                @Ajax.ActionLink(item.UserName, @*Text to be displayed *@
                    "GetUserDetails", @*Action Method Name*@
                    new AjaxOptions
                    {
                       UpdateTargetId = "CustomerDetails", @*DOM element ID to be updated *@
                       InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,@*Replace the content of DOM element *@
                       HttpMethod = "GET" @*HTTP method *@
                    }
                )
            </li>
        }
        </ul>
        <div id ="CustomerDetails">
            <h2>Student Details</h2>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <th>Student Name</th>
                    <th>User Name</th>
                    <th>Department</th>
                </tr>
                <tr>

                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="sidebar">
    </div>
    <div id="sidebarcontents">
        <ul id="menu">
            <li>
                <h2>Our Services</h2>
            </li>
            <li>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Link a   Website</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Website Link B</a></li>

                    <li><a href="#">Website Link C</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Small Businesses Website</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Flyer Website</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <div id="sidebarbottom"></div>
</div>
```

The issue is when I click on the hyperlink of the user name suppose "zack_dyas"

[image]

I dont know how would I get the ID (i.e. StudentID = 1) from the DB and display all the relevant details back related to that registed student in the div with id "CustomerDetails".

I cannot figure out the code. I am new to MVC.

Comment: Your model in the view is `StudentViewModel`, but your have not shown it. Does it contain a property for the StudentID? And what is the `GetUserDetails()` method (it needs a parameter for the ID and you link needs to pass that value to the method)

Comment: I could not figure out what and how to send ID to the method. Basically the code itself is not clear to me .View Model definition is included in the question though.

Comment: Not sure where to start (you have a few misunderstandings about what a view model is and how to use it). You method needs to be `GetUserDetails(int id)` and you pass the ID of the student to the method in the link - e.g. `@Ajax.ActionLink(item.UserName, "GetUserDetails", new { id = item.Student.StudentID, ...` but the model in you view should be `@model IEnumerable<Student>` not `StudentViewModel`